# Consolidating a list of folders by the top most

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost

I am looking for an algorithm that will take a list of folders and return a list of the "least" top level folders.

In other words, say my input is:

```
/abc/sub
/abc
/xxx/yyy/zzz
/xxx/yyy/zzz/iii/foobar
/www/zzz
/www/zzz/ppp
/www/xxx
```

The output should be

```
/abc
/xxx/yyy/zzz
/www/zzz
/www/xxx
```

I am free to use the Boost libraries, which might be helpful if there was an easy way to test if a folder was a subfolder of another folder arbitrarily higher up in the hierarchy, but I can't find anything like that.

The solutions I keep coming back to in my experimentation exponentially complex. I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing and if there's a better way.

Thank you!

Comment: You could build a simple set of tree structures (with a new tree for each new root) representing the file structure, with nodes representing folders. Simply keep a count of each time a node in the tree is hit, then BFS traverse the tree starting at the root and every node that has the same count as the root will be part of the 'common denominator' of the paths.

Comment: First, sort everything alphabetically. Then, traverse the sorted strings, finding the length of the common prefix between each one and its previous. For each run of items with a common prefix (length > 0), take the minimum of the prefix length so far and the current one. The minimum across each run is a 'least top-level folder'. This is linear in the number of strings (plus log-linear for the sort). The code is not complicated, it's just rather tedious, so I'll leave this purely as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You build a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), with each node being a path component. So when you see the first path, `/abc/sub`, your trie has two nodes:

```
abc
  - sub
```

When you see the `/abc`, you check the trie and see that it already exists as a top-level node, but you add an empty reference as a sub-node to indicate that you saw the path name as input, without anything following it. Then you get the next, `/xxx/yyy/zzz`, and your structure becomes:

```
abc
  - <empty>
  - sub
      - <empty>
xxx
  - yyy
      - zzz
          - <empty>
```

When you're done, your complete trie is:

```
abc
  - empty
  - sub
      - <empty>
xxx
  - yyy
      - zzz
          - <empty>
          - iii
              - foobar
                  - <empty>
www
  - zzz
      - <empty>
      - ppp
  - xxx
      - <empty>
```

The `<empty>` entries mean that you've seen a reference that terminated at that node. That is, you saw `/xxx/yyy/zzz`, but you never saw `/xxx/yyy` all by itself.

Now, you can traverse the trie to produce your output, using whatever rules you've defined to mean "least" top level. I think what you mean is that you want the highest-level nodes that don't branch.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is pretty concise:

```
void bottom(std::vector<std::string>& input)
{
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator curr = input.begin();

    std::vector<std::string>::iterator next = curr + 1;

    std::string::iterator last = curr->begin();

    // Sort lexicographically
    std::sort(input.begin(), input.end());

    while (next < input.end())
    {
        // Find next folder ending in current path
        last = std::find(++last, curr->end(), '/');

        // Temporary boolean
        bool equal = std::equal(curr->begin(), last, next->begin());

        // If the path so far is final, all other paths that go as far as or further
        // than this path fold into this path and can be deleted
        // If the current path is different from the next, we just increment to the
        // next path string because the current one must be a final level
        if (last == curr->end() || ! equal)
        {
            // The boolean is stored so that this check here isn't duplicated, but
            // the same if clause can be used for both possibilities stated above
            while (equal && next != input.end())
            {
                next = input.erase(next);

                // New next
                equal = std::equal(curr->begin(), last, next->begin());
            }

            curr = next++;

            last = curr->begin();
        }
    }
}
```